# Load large Tensorflow dataset in chunks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently trying to build a RNN to categorize the UCF101 dataset.

First I load the dataset using Tensorflows's built in method:

```
(train, test) = tfds.load('ucf101', split = ['train', 'test'], shuffle_files = False)
print("Training Size: ",len(train)) # 9,537
print("Teset Size: ",len(test)) # 3,783 examples
```

The UCF101 dataset is just over 6.5gb and therefore can't be loaded into memory all at once.
I would like to sequentially load chucks of the dataset into memory, like calling pop() on a a stack. For example, if the dataset was `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` I would like to call `data.pop(2)` and get `[1,2]`. The next time if I call `data.pop(3)` I would expect `[3,4,5]` and so on.

Tensorflow has the built in method `data.take(n)` but unfortunately it returns the same values instead of the next `n` values.

How can I load all of my large dataset chuck by chuck into memory without repeats? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to do a  `dataset.skip(2)` after `take`. For UCF101, you define train = train.batch(batch_size) and it will load `batch_size` to your model, without repeats within a epoch. Remember to shuffle as well.